# Is it better to use several SUBs or have all the code in one SUB

Tags: vba, ms-word

I have been teaching myself VBA through forums and YouTube. I have written some code that uses `If` statements. If the statement is true I have a choice of calling another SUB or just writing the code in the same SUB. My question is, if I call a SUB and it uses MS Word, if the code uses a loop, will it be the equivalent of starting MS Word then exiting and the restarting it again and again? I commented the parts that belong to the second SUB and did not include it below.

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub CreateWordDocEarlyBinding()
    'Declared Variables for Sub.
    Dim sourceDoc As String
    Dim lastRow As Long
    Dim rowLoop As Long

    'Adding code for MS Word here
    Dim WdApp As Application
    Set WdApp = New Word.Application

'Not sure I need this for any reason.    
Dim columnLoop As Long

    'Find last row.
    lastRow = Sheet1.Cells(Sheet1.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

    'Looping through column.
    For rowLoop = 2 To lastRow

         'Not sure I  need at this point for code.
         'columnLoop = Sheet1.Range(rowLoop, 1)

        'Checking cells for A Conditon.
        If Sheet1.Cells(rowLoop, 1).Value = "Test String 1" Then
            If Sheet1.Cells(rowLoop, 1).Offset(0, 1).Value >= 0.1 Then
                If Sheet1.Cells(rowLoop, 1).Offset(0, 1).Value < 1 Then
                    sourceDoc = "Test1.docx"
                    Call CreateNewSourceDoc(sourceDoc, WdApp)
                Else
                    sourceDoc = "Test2.docx"
                    Call CreateNewSourceDoc(sourceDoc, WdApp)
                End If

            End If

        'Checking cells for B condition.
        ElseIf Sheet1.Cells(rowLoop, 1).Value = "Test String 2" Then
            If Sheet1.Cells(rowLoop, 1).Offset(0, 1).Value >= 0.5 Then
                If Sheet1.Cells(rowLoop, 1).Offset(0, 1).Value < 5 Then
                    sourceDoc = "Test3.docx"
                    Call CreateNewSourceDoc(sourceDoc, WdApp)
                Else
                    sourceDoc = "Test4.docx"
                    Call CreateNewSourceDoc(sourceDoc, WdApp)
                End If
            End If



        End If

    'Checking next row.
    Next

    WdApp.Quit
    Set WdApp = Nothing
End Sub
```

I am adding the code I had for second SUB here for clarification. Does this code create a new instance of word every time it loops? If it does, would I be better off eliminating the below SUB.

```
Sub CreateNewSourceDoc(sourceDoc As String, WdApp As Application)

    'Declaring variables
    Dim newFolderName As String
    Dim newFilePath As String
    'Source folder
     filePath = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\"

     'New Folder
      newFolderName = Sheet1.Cells(rowLoop, 1) & " " & Sheet1.Cells(rowLoop, 2)
      MkDir filePath & newFolderName

      'New file path
            newFilePath = filePath & newFolderName & "\"

     'I commented the below code out to see if it is correct.
    'Set WdApp = New Word.Application

    With WdApp

              .Visible = False

              '.Activate

              .Documents.Open filePath & sourceDoc

              .ActiveDocument.SaveAs2 Filename:=newFilePath & Sheet1.Cells(rowLoop, 1) & " " & Sheet1.Cells(rowLoop, 2) & ".docx"


          End With

          sourceDoc = vbNullString

End Sub
```

Comment: If you pass your `WdApp` to the sub, it can use that. Otherwise it will have to start a new instance, yes.

Comment: @GSerg , not sure what you mean. I added the code to the post which consolidated two SUBs. When they were separated, the 1st SUB passed "sourceDoc" to the 2nd SUB which opened and saved the word doc. Where would I pass "wdApp" in order to avoid a new instance. Sorry I am new to this.

Comment: `New Word.Application` starts a new instance of Word every time it is executed, just as reading the code indicates it would. If you want to reuse one instance, then you'll have to pass `WdApp` into the second `SUB` in addition to `sourceDoc` that you're passing now; it would be passed as an additional argument to the second `SUB`.. I don't know where `WdApp` comes from, though; you use it in your first `SUB`, but it's not anywhere in that code except the single line `WdApp.Quit`.

Comment: @KenWhite , I edited the first SUB code and think I passed the WdApp and sourceDoc to the second sub. How's it look now?

Comment: Looks fine to me. Open Task Manager, make sure there are no orphaned Word instances from your previous efforts, then run your code. Do whatever you intend it to do, exit, and then check Task Manager for orphaned Word instances again. If there aren't any, then your code is fine.

Comment: @KenWhite , I only see one instance of word and it goes away at the end of the sub.Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code, as it stands in the question, is correct.

The `Word.Application` (`WdApp`) is started in the "main" Sub `CreateWordDocEarlyBinding` and also quit and cleaned up there.

`WdApp`, along with the document that is used, is then passed to the second Sub for processing.

There is one more thing I notice that could be optimized in this second procedure (Sub):

I would declare and instantiate a `Word.Document` object for the document being opened, then saved, rather than opening the document "anonomously" then relying on `ActiveDocument` to be the correct document. So...

```
Sub CreateNewSourceDoc(sourceDoc As String, WdApp As Application)

    'Declaring variables
    Dim newFolderName As String
    Dim newFilePath As String
    Dim wdDoc as Word.Document

     'New Folder
      newFolderName = Sheet1.Cells(rowLoop, 1) & " " & Sheet1.Cells(rowLoop, 2)
      MkDir filePath & newFolderName

     'New file path
     newFilePath = filePath & newFolderName & "\"

     With WdApp   
          .Visible = False
          Set wdDoc = .Documents.Open(filePath & sourceDoc)
          wdDoc.SaveAs2 Filename:=newFilePath & Sheet1.Cells(rowLoop, 1) & _
                        " " & Sheet1.Cells(rowLoop, 2) & ".docx"  
     End With

     sourceDoc = vbNullString
     Set wdDoc = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: I will add that to the code, and thanks to your explanation , I see how that would be better. I appreciate that. What else would you do to optimize the code? I am planning on adding another SUB which creates from worksheet. Would it be ideal to pass the "newFilePath"  to the Sub PDFMaker? I'd like the files generated for each loop of Sub CreateNewSourceDoc and Sub PDFMaker to be placed in same file.

Comment: A discussion about optimization is difficult (and off-topic) on Stack Overflow, which is more for specific questions. You might take a look at the Code Review site (be sure to read their Help for what's on-topic and how to ask there), see if that wouldn't be better for straight optimization discussions. Sure, pass the file path to both sub procedures.

Comment: Just be careful not to *change* the path inside either procedure. Read up on "By Ref" vs. "By Value" for parameters/arguments. A `String` will be By Ref by default, meaning any change is passed back to the calling procedure. If a local change is needed, specify the parameter as "By Value".

Comment: I did get errors using the default By Ref when the code looped back. When I changed it to  By Value, it worked nicely.